# Second monitor suddenly no longer detected after going into sleep mode. I dual-boot and the monitor works on Windows but not Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, laptop

As stated, my second monitor is no longer being detected after my laptop went into sleep-mode one day. The monitor works when I boot to windows but not on Ubuntu. I'm using nvidia-driver-525, I have trialled other versions and it still remained undetected. Currently using wayland but the monitor is not detected on xorg either. Monitor undetected on all prime profiles. My xrandr output is:

```
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
   1440x1080     59.99  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     59.89  
   1280x960      59.94  
   1152x864      59.96  
   1024x768      59.92  
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1600x900      59.95  
   1368x768      59.88  
   1280x720      59.86  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77
```

My laptop is an *Acer Nitro AN515-52*

I really don't wish to re-install Ubuntu as I have installed alot of packages and configured it to exactly my liking

**UPDATE**
For some reason the 2nd monitor **is** recognised when the **nouveau** drivers are used, but for none of the proprietary nvidia ones. I would very much rather be using the nvidia drivers for obvious reasons so this isn't a solution of me.